# Mapping OCRed text to numbers

Tags: python, text, mapping, ocr

I want to map extracted document type from some invoice to numbers. The rule is simple:

> 00 Απόδειξη Πώλησης Εισιτηρίων
> 01 Τιμολόγιο Συνδρομών
> 02
> Τιμολόγιο Παροχής Υπηρεσιών
> 03 ΤΙΜΟΛΟΓΙΟ
> 04 as None
> etc.

The problem is that in some invoices text is shortened (e.g. `Τιμολόγιο Συνδ.` or `Τιμολόγιο Παρ.Υπη.`) and may have some OCR errors (e.g. **φβχ;** `Τιμολόγιο Συν`**6**. or `Τιμολόγιο Παρ.`**Ynn**. **...δ**) .
I tried to use Levenshtein distance to deal with OCR errros but because of shortened text it messes all up (e.g. because even when extracted right `Τιμολόγιο Παρ.Υπη.` is closer to `ΤΙΜΟΛΟΓΙΟ` than to `Τιμολόγιο Παροχής Υπηρεσιών` in terms of characters and results in wrong mapping)

edit1: made errors bold

What should I do to improve mapping quality ?

Comment: I don't know greek, but it seems that your Levenshtein distance is case insensitive, but if it was case sensitive your example should be closer to the correct option (I think)

Comment: Maybe the right way to use levenschtein distance would be to try to correct the OCR errors word-by-word. Regarding the contractions, reverse them: have some dictionary of short forms and map back to long forms. Like Παρ with or without a period goes back to Παροχής.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved using a simple model for sentence classification:

```
model = Sequential()          #21           100                50
model.add(layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, input_length=maxlen))
model.add(layers.Conv1D(128, 5, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(8, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Embeddings were made of character level tokenized strings. Seems like NN learned some patterns of letters and even with more mistakes the types are classified correctly.